# installing ubuntu on windows and LVM option

Tags: windows, usb-installation

While installing ubuntu on windows , during installation it is giving me 2 options to work within the advance section either , installation with `LVM` or `none`. So, should I go with `LVM` or normal installation

Comment: Does "*installing ubuntu on windows*" mean installing Ubuntu into a Virtual Machine on a Windows host? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: ohh , i mean replacing it altogther

Comment: Do you understand what the LVM-vs-None choice means? Or are you asking for an explanation? Advice: If you don't know what LVM is, choose None.